# Javascript inheritance of static properties

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, static

Struggling a bit with inheritance of static properties. My Main class has a static property `a`. I would like for my Sub class to override that property. Also, I can only access 'a' in the constructor using `Main.a`. I would like that `new Sub()` uses `Sub.a` in its constructor. Can I do this, if so, how?

```
class Main {

    static a = "Is Main";
  
  constructor() {
    
    console.log( "Constructor Main " + Main.a)  // "Is Main"
    console.log( "Constructor This " + this.a)  // undefined
  }
  
}
class Sub extends Main {
    static a = "Is Sub"
}

var sub = new Sub();
console.log( sub.a );       // undefined

 /*
Constructor Main Is Main
Constructor This undefined
undefined 
*/
```

Comment: `this.constructor.a` should work for dynamic static variable resolution.

Comment: Got me in the right direction. 'this.constructor.a' works to get at 'sub.a' everywhere except in a static method where you have to use 'this'. Thanks for the start.